# How to Format Power BI Table / Matrix Regardless Of Values

Tags: powerbi

I am very new to Power BI and I have this requirement to format the table which is not conditional formatting but kind a hard coding formatting.

*First Row  Column 1 is Yellow, Columns 2, 3 and 4 are Red
Second Row Column 1 is Green, Column 2 and 3 are Yellow, Column 4 is Red
Third Row Column 1, 2, 3 and 4 are Green
Fourth Row No Colour*
I have also attached the pic below
[image: Click for image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is not possible. The reason is, all columns are generated dynamically based on your data in the table. That's why you need to apply conditions to color cells as you want.

Now, as you showed in the sample presentation, if you have that fixed amount of rows and columns with known fixed values in different cells, you can use CARD visual for each individual value to show and then use your expected background.Not a good approach, but the end user will see the expected output :)

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind response. Have done it via CARDS

Comment: @AliShah Nice to see my instruction helped. You can put an upvote as well :)